# Angular: ¿Como muestro una imagen default en caso de tener un resultado null desde api?

Tags: angular

Tengo un observable que me trae el logo de una agencia y esto funciona. Pero a veces puede suceder que no tenga una agencia asignada entonces tengo que mostrar una img default pero me está costando hacer la condicional porque no puedo comprobar si viene null o no la respuesta porque me dice que logo no es una propiedad del observable pero si lo es.

```
//TS
 export class NavbarComponent {
      public agenciaData$: Observable<DatosAgencia>
      constructor(private service: Service) {
        this.agenciaData$ = service.datosAgencia;
      }
}


export interface DatosAgencia {
    color_principal:  string;
    color_secundario: string;
    logo:             string;
}

//HTML
    <img
      routerLink="/home"
       src="{{ (agenciaData$ | async)?.logo }}"
      slot="end"
      alt="logo"
    />
```

Comment: Haz probado con la propiedad onerror de la etiqueta img? https://jsfiddle.net/oLqfxjoz/

Comment: Hola Giuliana, es un bucle o una respuesta única, si este fuera el caso, puedes probar **[src]=" (agenciaData$ | async)?.logo == null? 'assets/img/default.png': (agenciaData$ | async)?.logo  ", espero que te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción.

```
<img *ngif="(agenciaData$ | async)?.logo!= null"
      routerLink="/home"
       src="{{ (agenciaData$ | async)?.logo }}"
      slot="end"
      alt="logo"
    />
<img *ngif="(agenciaData$ | async)?.logo == null"
      routerLink="/home"
       src="assets/img/default.png"
      slot="end"
      alt="logo"
    />
```

Espero que te sirva.